# DataGridView selected rows to DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, selection

I'm trying to add only the selected rows of a DataGridView to a DataTable, the code that I'm using always start from the first row even if this one is not selected... Does someone have an idea for how to fix this please?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Rapport");

// Generating columns to datatable
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    dt.Columns.Add(column.Name, typeof(string));

// Adding selected rows of DGV to DataTable
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add();
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        dt.Rows[i][j] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to access `SelectedRows` like

```
dt.Rows[i][j] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value;
```

Also its better if your `DataTable` has the same type as of Cell

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    dt.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.CellType); //better to have cell type
```

So your code would be:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    dt.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.CellType); //better to have cell type
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{
     dt.Rows.Add();
     for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
         dt.Rows[i][j] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                                   //^^^^^^^^^^^
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable dt = ((DataTable)dgvQueryResult.DataSource).Clone();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvQueryResult.SelectedRows)
{
    dt.ImportRow(((DataTable)dgvQueryResult.DataSource).Rows[row.Index]);
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
```