# Setting the Column value of one gridview as the datasource of another gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I have two gridviews. One gridview datasource is setting through the database. Now I want that when I click on the Row of the first gridview its first column value of the selected row should be set to the second gridview.

```
    private void masterTab1_ItemSelected(object sender, object selectedValue)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            SerialNumberGrid.Columns.Add("SerialNumber");
            SerialNumberGrid.DataSource = masterTab1.HeaderGrid.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
     }
```

I am doing it this way But its giving me the index out of range exception.

[image]

Comment: Row or cell ? in your code , you selected cell value ! isn't it ?

Comment: The First cell of the Selected Row

Comment: what about your second gridView's data fields and columns ? It has only one column ?

Comment: Yes I want to show only one column and I want to generate it through code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create a DataTable and add your selected cell's value to it as a DataRow !

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("yourField", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add(masterTab1.HeaderGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

And set this `table` as your Second grid's datasourse .

```
 SerialNumberGrid.DataSource = table ;
 SerialNumberGrid.DataBind();
```

**Edit**

You should get your selected cell value likes

```
 masterTab1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

or

```
 masterTab1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

And you should know how to convert [DataGridView selected rows to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19639641/1427849) !

Comment: Its again giving me the index out of range exception

Comment: is your grid multiple rows selectable ?

Comment: Yes and when I pass that cell value into the table.Rows.Add its giving me the exception

Comment: Yes I am doing it like this but the same exception is coming. And I also want to know that how can I get the value of all of the selected rows from the first gridview also Edited the Post @zey

Comment: See my edit , I've added a link , follow it and convert your selected rows to DataTable , and bind this dataTable to your Second GridView !

Comment: Your code is only working for the single select how an I do that for multiple? @zey