# How to convert DataGrid to dataTable

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I want to copy all the datagrid records into datatable without using any loop.
For Ex:

```
Dim dt as New DataTable
dt = Datagrid1.Items
```

But this is not Working and giving an error message.

My Development platform is Visual studio 2010 and language is WPF with vb.net 4.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the way to transfer all the records from DATAGRID to DATATABLE without using the LOOP.

**VB:**

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = CType(DataGrid1.ItemsSource, DataView).ToTable
```

**C#:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ((DataView)DataGrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

Comment: I'm not finding "ItemSource" on a C# datagrid

Comment: how to do it with mvvm

Answer (score 5):

It depends how the datagrid is populated. If the DataContext property is set to a DataTable then you can simply just retrieve this value and cast to a DataTable.

There is no direct method to convert this to a DataTable from the DataGrid element.

If you wanted to do this manually, you would have to create an instance of the DataTable, then create the rows from the Items in the DataGrid using a loop.

Answer (score 2):

To convert your dataGrid into data table whith header row you can follow this steps:

1) create the method to retrive the cell

```
  static public DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dg, int row, int column)
    {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dg, row);

        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                dg.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dg.Columns[column]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

2) Iterate through all items and pass the content to dada table "cell"

```
    private void DataGridToDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        var j = byte.MinValue;//header row handler
        dt.Rows.Add();
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in dataGrid1.Columns)
        {                
            dt.Columns.Add(column.GetValue(NameProperty).ToString());
            dt.Rows[byte.MinValue][j++] = column.Header;
        }

        //data rows handler
        for (int i = byte.MinValue ; i < dataGrid1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            for (j = Byte.MinValue; j < dataGrid1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                DataGridCell dgc = GetCell(dataGrid1, i, j);
                dt.Rows[i + 1][j] =  ((dgc.Content) as TextBlock).Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind to use this methods you must will reference this using

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

And here a helper class just to use it.

```
 /// <summary>
/// Class to help to retrive the Data Grid Contain
/// </summary>
public static class DataGridHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrive the cell contains
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dg">DataGrid</param>
    /// <param name="row">row</param>
    /// <param name="column">column</param>
    /// <returns>DataGrid Cell content</returns>
    static public DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dg, int row, int column)
    {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dg, row);

        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

            // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
                dg.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dg.Columns[column]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get row content
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dg">Datagrid</param>
    /// <param name="index">Index</param>
    /// <returns>DataGridRow</returns>
    static public DataGridRow GetRow(DataGrid dg, int index)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {
            // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
            dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }
    static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this to work just fine, but I had to add my own GetVisualChild and GetRow methods because they aren't posted here.

Comment: Sorry Forgot, but like you see it's easy to create your own method to retrive row and GetVisulaChild.
Let me know if you wants tha I posted this methods too

Comment: Could you add these methods to make the answer complete?

Comment: Hi jeremy I add the helper class I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

i just tested this and this works

```
Dim dt as New DataTable
dt = ctype(Datagrid1.Datasource, DataTable)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to loop on DataGrid and add item to Datatable. below link may help.

[DataGridView selected rows to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639641/datagridview-selected-rows-to-datatable)