# Convert DataGrid to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datagrid

What's the equivalent in .NET to convert my `DataGrid` to a `DataTable` (`DataGrid.ItemsSource` isn't defined in .Net csharp.

Thanks!

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ((DataView)DataGrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

**EDIT**

This isn't a duplicate since the previous code is for WPF and I'm looking for an asp.net mvc csharp answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert DataGrid to dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827339/how-to-convert-datagrid-to-datatable)

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters No. The duplicate post's code is same as the OP's code and since he/she mentioned *`DataGrid.ItemsSource` isn't defined* so he/she definitely is not looking for a WPF solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` is for WPF. Use the `DataSource` and cast it to `DataTable` like this:

```
dt = (DataTable)DataGrid1.DataSource;
```

**EDIT**: And if you get into trouble with above approach, you can use a custom method like this:

```
private DataTable ToDataTable(DataGridView dataGridView)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn in dataGridView.Columns)
    {
        if (dataGridViewColumn.Visible)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add();
        }
    }
    var cell = new object[dataGridView.Columns.Count];
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in dataGridView.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            cell[i] = dataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(cell);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

And then use it:

```
var dataTable = ToDataTable(dataGridView1);
```

Also `MoreLinq` is a good choice in case the type of `Datasource` is a list. Check this solution to know how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42550827/2946329

Comment: I tried it and I get this error: Can't cast 'System.Collections.Generic.List' in type 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: @J.Lavoie - see my answer

Comment: @J.Lavoie OK. Check my updated answer. I provided another approach to achieve this.

Comment: What's the using I need in order to use DataGridView? Intellisense can't find me one

Comment: @S.Akbari the OP is working in ASP.NET MVC. DataGridView is a WinForms control.

Comment: @bnem OK. I know. BTW the MVC doesn't contain any helper called `DataGrid`.

Comment: @J.Lavoie The using is this: `using System.Windows.Forms;`

Comment: @J.Lavoie Another option is `MoreLinq` if the type of `Datasource` is a list. Check my updated answer again.

Comment: Beware, this method fails in presence of invisible columns. In the first ``foreach`` it takes it into account, but in the second one no. So in case of an invisble column , in the second ``foreach``  try to put data out of range.   Tried myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid` or `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid`, then the best way would be to cast the `Datasource` property to a `DataTable`.

Of course the `Datasource` property has to actually be a `DataTable` underlying type to begin with. You need to know the underlying type of the object stored in the `Datasource` property.

If the underlying type of `Datasource` is a generic list, then this SO post should help: [How to convert a list into data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100783/how-to-convert-a-list-into-data-table)

FYI - The Windows Forms `DataGrid` control, [according to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx), has been replaced by the `DataGridView`.

Comment: I'm referring to the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid`

Comment: @J.Lavoie yes saw your edit and updated my answer, added a link to converting list to datatable

Comment: I have an error when casting, but maybe it's because the underlying type of the object stored is a class object!

Comment: @J.Lavoie in your comment on the other answer, you had an error because you were trying convert a generic list to a `Datatable`. Use the link I provided in my answer.

Comment: Ok this work perfectly except that my datetime values are converted in decimal!

Answer (score 0):

if there is visible columns in datagridview you can use

```
    private DataTable ToDataTable(DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        int columnCount = 0;
        List<int> columnNumbers= new List<int>();

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn in dataGridView.Columns)
        {


            if (dataGridViewColumn.Visible)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(dataGridViewColumn.Name);                   
                columnNumbers.Add(columnCount);

            }
            columnCount++;
        }

        var cell = new object[columnNumbers.Count];
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (int a in columnNumbers)
            {
                cell[i] = dataGridViewRow.Cells[a].Value;
                i++;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(cell);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom method does not take into account the hidden columns. You are getting an error, because you have too many cells for the columns copied.

You can use :

```
int dgv1RowCount = dgv1.Rows.Count;
int numOfColumns = dgv1.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) ;
int numCells = dgv1RowCount * numOfColumns;
// use numCells in the for loop
for (int i = 0; i < numOfCells ; i++)
{
    enter code here
}
```