# how do i convert dataGrid into Data table in wpf c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I want to calculate total sum for a column, data showing in a DataGrid. but I have to convert Datagrid into data table to access or use that column.
The data is coming from a rest-API built-in dot net core.

**How can I convert data grid into data table?**

XAML:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="272" Margin="391,70,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="527" x:Name="GridCustomerSupplied" 
    SelectionChanged="GridCustomerSupplied_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Calling Method:

```
BindCustomerSuppliedGrid(GridCustomerSupplied,GetCurrentDate());
```

The error I get:

> Unable to cast object of type 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MilkManagementUI.Models.ResponseModels.CustomerSuppliedResponseDto]' to type 'System.Data.DataView'.

C#:

```
public static void BindCustomerSuppliedGrid(DataGrid grid,string date)
{
    try
    {
        var response = RestApiHelper<IEnumerable<CustomerSupplied>>.
            GetAll($"api/CustomerSupplied/all/date/{date}");

        grid.ItemsSource = response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert DataGrid to dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827339/how-to-convert-datagrid-to-datatable)

Comment: i have used this . but this is giving me this error:-                                
 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MilkManagementUI.Models.ResponseModels.CustomerSuppliedResponseDto]' to type 'System.Data.DataView'.'

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried

Comment: i have tried this code:-   DataTable dt = new DataTable();dt = ((DataView)GridCustomerSupplied.ItemsSource).ToTable();

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data;

[...]

// Create DataTable
DataTable DataTable_Export = new DataTable();

// Instert DataGrid into DataTable
DataTable_Export = ((DataView)DataGrid_Input.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

Thats all you Need to do.