# How do I work with a datagridview in a window and show its results in another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've started a Windows application in C# via Visual Studio. So far, so good, but now I have a problem. I'm working with a sql database, which has a lot of tables. Suddenly, I don't know how to show a selected search result in the main window, since I only know how to work with it within the same form, but not how to show it's results in another form. I know how to manage the datagridview, but I don't know how to show it's selected results in a different windows form.
In any case you need pictures of it or code lines, I can upload them later (I'm working right now).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataGridView selected rows to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639641/datagridview-selected-rows-to-datatable)

Answer (score 2):

What is the relationship between the two forms? Open the form contains DataGridView from Main form? If so, you can use delegate to transfer data.

MainForm.cs:

```
void frm_TransfEvent(string value)
{
    lbResult.Text = value;
}

private void btOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.TransfEvent += frm_TransfEvent;
    form1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
public event TransfDelegate TransfEvent;

private void btSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowindex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    TransfEvent(dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ", " + dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    this.Close();
}
```

The test result,

[image]

**Update:**

First, we need to define a property in calss `Form2` to access the label you want to modify.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Label labelProperty
    {
        get { return label1; }
        set { label1 = value; }
    }

    private void btOpenForm3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 form3 = new Form3();
        form3.Show();
    }
}
```

Then open `Form7` form `Form3`.

```
private void btOpenForm7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form7 form7 = new Form7();
    form7.Show();
}
```

To transfer data from `Form7` to `Form2`, you can use [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netcore-3.1) to get the instance of `Form2` and access the label via property `labelProperty`.

```
public partial class Form7 : Form
{
    public Form7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btUpdateForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
        form2.labelProperty.Text = "Test 123";
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my. Pretty much it's what I need to do. I knew how to manage data in the same form, but not from Form1 to MainForm. It should work from Form3 to Form2, right? Since I use MainForm just to make login to the system.

Comment: btw, this should work the same for other Forms? Or does it only with Form1 to MainForm? Because I use MainForm for login.

Comment: This method is used to transfer data from `child form` to `parent form`. So what is the relationship between Form2 and Form3?

Comment: Form2 is parent of Form3. It already worked out just fine. Should it work from other forms that are executed from Form3? Let's say Form7 and Form9, both of them come out of Form3. This should work out too right?

Comment: @G.J.Gonzalez. Do you mean that Form3 is opened form Form2, Form7&9 are opened form Form3 and you wnat to transfer the data form From7&9 to Form2? If so, I recommend using [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netcore-3.1). I have updated the answer, you can check it. If any misunderstanding, please contact me.

Comment: thank you very much, I will check it later and tell you how it went.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `SelectionChanged()` event of the `DataGridView` on your result form and have it call a method to do something on your main form, passing it the needed data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1